# How to stop an external hard drive from unmounting

Tags: 16.04, mount, suspend, usb-drive, external-hdd

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on old MacBook hardware. I have an external drive connected to the computer via USB. After a few minutes of non-use, the screen goes dark and when I touch the keyboard again it's on the Ubuntu login page, and the external drive via USB is unmounted (when I ssh into the computer and check my /media folder it's no longer there.

How do I make it so that the external drive is ALWAYS mounted/present at the /media folder?

Comment: How are you mounting it?   It sounds like you're being logged out (screen going dark & login again) thus media is disconnected. If it was mounted via fstab (file system table) you have more control over when mounted (auto, noauto etc) though there will be alternatives.  Thus how do you mount it?

Comment: Hi @guiverc I'm mounting it just by plugging the hard drive in via USB. Ideally I want to make this external hard drive an extension of the computer, so that the folders within it are always available, even if I'm logged out.

Comment: As already stated, I would have made an entry via your file system table, the way you're describing makes it available to your account (ie. GUI mounts it as a user function) so it won't remain available afterwards (ie. if logged out) I believe.   Why not use `blkid` to get details of drive, so you can then add to your fstab  (use UUID and not /dev/* detail which can change).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm not familiar with the fstab. I'll google on that and give it a try

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab   (I'd recommend sticking with official documentation if possible unless you're capable of *vetting* the sources yourself).  ie. for Ubuntu i'd use `site:*.ubuntu.com` in searches (startpage.com for me).   Your existing partition(s) are a huge clue; use `blkid` to get UUID or unique ID's (don't use /dev/sd?? device names as these can change if another OS or you make changes to settings/BIOS/UEFI or mount in different orders for external media etc)